# Why is EF adding a collection of objects to a table that has no foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am doing DB First Modeling and I have a table called List.Country. This table has no foreign keys of its own. it is just a PK, Name, and Code.

When EF maps the table over however, it adds three Virtual ICollections of entities that have a foreign key to the List.Country table.

Why is EF doing this? The Country entity should not care who uses it. It should only care about what it does itself. The Entities that have foreign keys to the Country table are correctly mapped with a country object in it.

Why is EF mapping uneeded properties. This causes problems in Integration testing because I now have to account for those objects even though they have nothing to do with the country object itself.

Comment: That's just how the designer is designed.  It is designed for the 95% of cases where a link-back _is_ desired.  Why can't you just delete the relationship in the designer?

Comment: Can you post your model? Most likely you have some type of virtual object in your model that is causing this to occur.

Comment: It is just the default you get 2 way mapping, you can adjust this in the designer it is not carved in stone.

Comment: @DStanley I would only want to delete Navigation properties not the actual relationship. How would I go about doing that?